# how to get multiple video and player image in one page my website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create multiple videos with player images on the videos on my website.

Player images have to `toggle` with click user.

In this code, it worked with id for one video and the same player image, **but** by inserting `multiple videos`, this code **not** work.

I need this code worked for multiple videos on one page for my website.

Please help me do it.

```js
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
var x = document.getElementById('playback-animation')

videoPlayer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  x.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.my-video {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--c4);
  margin: var(--mr);
}

.playback-animation {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -55px;
  margin-top: -55px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
}

.playback-animation.active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="meeting--videos">
  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                  <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none" stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                  <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                  <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                </g>
                <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none" stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                    <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                    <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                </g>
                <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35" transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                  <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z" transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
 </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>

  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                                        <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                                            <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35"
                                                transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                                            <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                                                <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"
                                                    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z"
                                                    transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
    </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>

  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                                        <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                                            <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35"
                                                transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                                            <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                                                <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"
                                                    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z"
                                                    transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
    </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problème is that you are using 'id' instead of 'class'. You cannot use 'id' to select more than one HTMLelement. So you should rename the id of your html code also.

```js
//Select all videoPlayer by using their class name.
var videoPlayers = document.getElementsByClassName('videoPlayer');
for(let vidPlayer of videoPlayers){
    vidPlayer.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //Select the element with class '.playback-animation' associated with vidPlayer.
        let x=vidPlayer.parentElement.querySelector('.playback-animation');
        x.classList.toggle("active");
    })
}
```

```css
.my-video {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--c4);
  margin: var(--mr);
}

.playback-animation {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -55px;
  margin-top: -55px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
}

.playback-animation.active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="meeting--videos">
  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation1">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                  <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none" stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                  <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                  <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                </g>
                <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none" stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                    <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                    <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                </g>
                <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35" transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                  <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z" transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
 </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer1" class="videoPlayer" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>

  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation2">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                                        <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                                            <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35"
                                                transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                                            <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                                                <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"
                                                    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z"
                                                    transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
    </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer2" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>

  <div class="my-video">
    <div class="playback-animation" id="playback-animation3">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="110" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
                                        <g id="Group_2579" data-name="Group 2579" transform="translate(-1330 -1514)">
                                            <g id="Ellipse_69" data-name="Ellipse 69" transform="translate(1330 1514)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="1">
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="55" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="54.5" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <g id="Ellipse_70" data-name="Ellipse 70" transform="translate(1340 1524)" fill="none"
                                                stroke="#E64A19" stroke-width="2" opacity="0.736">
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="45" stroke="none"></circle>
                                                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="44" fill="none"></circle>
                                            </g>
                                            <circle id="Ellipse_71" data-name="Ellipse 71" cx="35" cy="35" r="35"
                                                transform="translate(1350 1534)" fill="#E64A19" opacity="0.996"></circle>
                                            <g id="play-button-arrowhead" transform="translate(1365.122 1556.063)">
                                                <path id="Path_77" data-name="Path 77"
                                                    d="M12.274.563C9.973-.757,8.107.324,8.107,2.976V22.548c0,2.655,1.866,3.735,4.167,2.416l17.106-9.81c2.3-1.321,2.3-3.46,0-4.78Z"
                                                    transform="translate(3 0)" fill="#fff"></path>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
    </div>
    <video width="100%" id="videoPlayer" class="videoPlayer3" controls>
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/webm">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @haniye Remember to check answers you find useful. It gives the answerer a confidence boost seeing those numbers tick up.